# python multivariable linear regression

Tags: python

So I'm trying to do a multivariable linear regression with python. But I can't do it because my dataset has the size (2920x1). I want to split the columns like this image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd2PO.png) but I have they separated with ";". 
How can I do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeBaU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd2PO.png)

Comment: Did you load data using pandas.read_csv?

Comment: yes, I've used ... Since I'm importing data from a CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would have had a pandas.DataFrame with one column looking like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a;b;c;d': ['2;3;1;6', '0;1;4;2', '6;9;6;0']})
>>> print(df)
   a;b;c;d
0  2;3;1;6
1  0;1;4;2
2  6;9;6;0
```

you could have used [`pandas.Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`pandas.Series.to_list()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) to make a new data frame.

The code is following.

```
>>> df_adjusted = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(';').to_list(), columns=df.columns[0].split(';'))
>>> print(df_adjusted)
   a  b  c  d
0  2  3  1  6
1  0  1  4  2
2  6  9  6  0
```

---

**Edit:**

For reading CSV file where cells are separated by semicolon, use [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function with properly filled `sep` parameter.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/data', sep=';')
```

Comment: Thanks! :) but I'm loading a CSV file. I think this is not the right thing to use in this case

Comment: @BernardoAugusto I am sorry. I misunderstood your question. I have just edited my answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I am glad I could have helped. However, If answer is correct and helpful, consider [further actions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).